# RPC with Express JS?

Tags: javascript, rest, node.js, rpc

I've been working on a project recently where I have an Expressjs server that supplies weather forecast data to its clients. Right now, I'm using express simply as a means of exposing some functions I have on the server. Here are some of my endpoints:

`GET /web/getFullForecast`

`GET /web/getCurrentForecast`

As you can see, the API is not REST but rather more RPC style.

Is it considered bad practice to use the express framework simply as a means of doing RPC? Would I be better served using some kind of RPC framework for this?

Comment: Why do you consider this RPC, not REST?  What about it would make you think it's not a good match for Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a short look into the [ExpressJS docs about routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), I cannot find any recommendation for or against using a RESTful style. On the contrary, there seem to be no restrictions imposed by the framework on how to choose URIs. So if the framework serves you well, don't overthink this.